# Change a string in the middle of the sentence with JS

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a little application that allows me to select between some checkboxes with lang codes and then with a click in a button, open new tabs with the URL with the lang-code changed.

URL FORMAT: https://example.com/**en-us**/example.html

What i want to change is the en-us. I have several issues here:

1. I know how to search a string, but there is a way to replace it avoiding a LOT of **if** statements? Because the web could have en-US code or maybe ko-KR or es-ES and so on.
2. I want to open a new tab for each checkbox(checked) with the selected lang-code.

So, there is a simple way to do this?

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">


</head>

<body>

<div class="container">
<div class="info-container">
    <p>URL:</p>
    <input type="text" id="URL">
    <input type="button" id="opentab-button" value="Go!">
</div>

<div class="langcode-container">
    <input type="checkbox" name="lang-check" value="ko-kr"> KOR<br>
    <input type="checkbox" value="lang-check" value="nl-NL"> NLD<br>
    <input type="checkbox" value="lang-check"> PTB<br>
    <input type="checkbox" value="lang-check"> PTG<br>      
    <input type="checkbox" value="lang-check"> CHT<br>      
</div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/index.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("opentab-button").addEventListener("click", openTabs);

function openTabs() {
    var str = document.getElementById("URL").value;     
    var checkQua = $(":checkbox:checked").length;
    for (i = 1; i <= checkQua; i++) {
        var res = str.replace("en-us", "ko-kr");    
        window.open(res,'_blank');  
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this can help you

```js
$(function(){
 
 $("#opentab-button").on("click", openTabs);

 function openTabs() { 

  var str = document.getElementById("URL").value;  
  var data = getLocation(str); 
  
  // passing by each checkbox
  $("[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function(){
  
   var path = data.pathname.split('/');
   // Replacing the second item (the language) for the value in the checkbox
   path.splice(1,1,$(this).val());
   
   // Replacing the old path of url by the new path
   var newPath = data.full.replace(data.pathname,path.join('/'));
    
   //window.open(newPath,'_blank');
            alert(newPath);
  });
 }
 
 function getLocation(url) {

  var reURLInformation = new RegExp([
   // protocol
   '^(https?:)//',
   // host (hostname and port)
   '(([^:/?#]*)(?::([0-9]+))?)',
   // pathname
   '(/[^?#]*)',
   // search
   '(\\?[^#]*|)',
   // hash
   '(#.*|)$'
  ].join(''));

  var match = url.match(reURLInformation);

  return match && {
   full: url,
   protocol: match[1],
   host: match[2],
   hostname: match[3],
   port: match[4],
   pathname: match[5],
   search: match[6],
   hash: match[7]
  }
 }
});
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="info-container">
    <p>URL:</p>
    <input type="text" id="URL">
    <input type="button" id="opentab-button" value="Go!">
</div>

<div class="langcode-container">
    <input type="checkbox" value="ko-kr"> KOR<br>
    <input type="checkbox" value="nl-NL"> NLD<br>
    <input type="checkbox" value="lang-check"> PTB<br>
    <input type="checkbox" value="lang-check"> PTG<br>      
    <input type="checkbox" value="lang-check"> CHT<br>      
</div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Perfect!! Thank you very much!

Comment: It's bad form to copy and paste code into your answer without mentioning its source.

Answer (score 2):

> I know how to search a string, but there is a way to replace it avoiding a LOT of if statements? Because the web could have en-US code or maybe ko-KR or es-ES and so on.

Keep the replacement values in the checkboxes' `value` attributes, as you've already done with your first two `<input>`s. Then, instead of `str.replace("en-us", "ko-kr")`, do `str.replace("en-us", checkbox.value)`.

```js
document.getElementById("opentab-button").addEventListener("click", openTabs);

function openTabs() {
  var str = document.getElementById("URL").value;
  var checkQua = document.querySelectorAll('input[name=lang-check]:checked');

  checkQua.forEach(function(checkbox) {
    var res = str.replace('en-us', checkbox.value);
    console.log('Opening', res);
    window.open(res, '_blank');
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="info-container">
  <p>URL:</p>
  <input type="text" id="URL" value="https://example.com/en-us/example.html">
  <input type="button" id="opentab-button" value="Go!">
</div>

<div class="langcode-container">
  <input type="checkbox" name="lang-check" value="ko-KR"> KOR<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="lang-check" value="nl-NL"> NLD<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="lang-check" value="pt-BR"> PTB<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="lang-check" value="pt-PT"> PTG<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="lang-check" value="ch-CH"> CHT<br>
</div>
```

Note that the above doesn't actually open any windows because Stack Overflow has disabled popups in snippets. (Take a look at your console to see the permission errors.)

Comment: wow! This worked nice. Now i have to figure out how to compare the "en-us", because not always the url came with that code. Could be: https://example.com/ko-kr/example.html and i  don't know if the best way is to put a lot of compares or not

Comment: Should be easy enough to swap out the str.replace with a regex.

Comment: This would do the trick - `var res = str.replace(/(?!\/)\w{2}\-\w{2}(?=\/)/g, checkbox.value);`

Answer (score -1):

```
var str = document.getElementById("URL").value
var res = str.replace(str.split("/")[3],"whateveryouwant")
window.open(res,'_blank');
```

Comment: I need to open a new tab for EACH checkbox(checked) with it's value replacing the lang-code.